# SQL Developer - rollback lockal change only for current line

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How could I revert local changes to the current line in SQL Developer, not using rollback, to safe other inserted rows and prevent changes to the current line

[image]

(current line means old record, that already stored in DB and has only local sloppy change)

Comment: commit or rollback is going to apply to everything pending in that table, you can't say JUST commit these 4 but not this one. So probably better to update one at a time and commit as you go

Comment: Don't make the change until it's certain that the change really *needs* to be made.

Comment: Sometimes I'm accidentally change some value - if I press Esc then I could revert this incomplete change and don't make local change on current row. In this case I insert for about 50 rows and one of them changed by miss shot =) I took with a select statement that value. If there a star* on the row-line - if it means that I could only rollback all local changes, and there is no possibility to cancel only change one line? Thank you for your responses

Comment: For all its usefulness I would not routinely use the data grid as a general-purpose data updating tool.